# Parse user and Facebook user link

Tags: android, parse-platform

i am using https://www.parse.com in a application. I need link two account: comum account + account facebook from my user. I  try use the next routine:

```
if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
    ParseFacebookUtils.link(user, Account.this, new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException ex) {
            if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                Log.e("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But apparently the done method is not implemented. Has anyone done this and could help me?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem adding the onActivityResult like this

```
      @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: great , I forgot to add it to my MainActivity... ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very well documented tutorial on integrating Facebook user account with ParseUser for Android. Incase you haven't checked it out, https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-android

Comment: Yes, that is a good tutorial, but it doesn't answer the question. The question is in reference to the LINK method and why it isn't calling DONE.